# POST method does not redirects to the controller action

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, post, controller

I have a simple html form in JSP and I am using spring mvc. 
I am trying to create a new user using POST method. 
The JSP code is :

```
<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="user">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>SJSU ID</td>
            <td><input type="text" placeholder="6 digit SJSU ID" id="sjsuid" name="sjsuid"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>EmailID</td>
            <td><input type="text" placeholder="Email ID" id="username" name="username"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3"><input type="submit" value="Create"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
</form:form>
```

Now, as specified in the form tag, I am trying to access the form values in my controller action as :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String submitForm(@ModelAttribute("user") User userVO) {
        System.out.println("Submitted");
        userDAO.createUser(userVO.getSjsuid(),userVO.getUsername());
        return "adduser";
    }
}
```

THe thins is , I am not getting a sysout message "Submitted" . In short, the submitForm action is never called. 
Can anyone tell me what is wrong ? 
I dont think there is some spring configuration isues because the same setup worked fine with another previous project.

Thanks.

Comment: You are missing the action attribute of the form that link your form submission with the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue by adding:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
```

Silly mistakes bugs me -_-